# What is the right way to fetch records by passing array of values to stored procedure parameters?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have following tables:

**expense_bugdet_head_master**:

```
Expense_Budget_ID   Transaction_ID  Transaction_Date        Department_ID   Branch_ID   Project_ID  Start_Date                  End_Date                Description
1                   EBF151600001    2015-11-07 00:00:00.000 NULL            NULL        GENERAL     2015-01-01  00:00:00.000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 Personal Computer
2                   EBF151600002    2015-11-07 00:00:00.000 NULL            NULL        GENERAL     2015-01-01  00:00:00.000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 UPS
3                   EBF151600003    2015-11-07 00:00:00.000 NULL            NULL        GENERAL     2015-01-01  00:00:00.000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 AC
4                   EBF151600004    2015-11-07 00:00:00.000 NULL            NULL        GENERAL     2015-01-01  00:00:00.000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 Laptop
5                   EBF151600005    2015-11-07 00:00:00.000 NULL            NULL        GENERAL     2015-01-01  00:00:00.000    2015-12-31 00:00:00.000 Generator
```

**expense_bugdet_head_detail**

```
Expense_Budget_Detail_ID    Expense_Budget_ID   Expense_Budget_Type_ID  Amount      Description         SL_Code Last_Modified_By    last_Modified_Date
1                           1                   NULL                    91310.00    Personal Computer   795031  NULL                NULL
2                           2                   NULL                    98810.00    UPS                 795031  NULL                NULL
3                           3                   NULL                    642344.00   AC                  795031  NULL                NULL
4                           4                   NULL                    1364000.00  Laptop              795031  NULL                NULL
5                           5                   NULL                    2377372.00  Generator           795031  NULL                NULL
```

This is my stored procedure which I recently created:

```
-- demo 'UPS,AC'
ALTER PROCEDURE demo
    @Budget_Description varchar(500) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @arr_str VARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @Temp_table Table (column1 VARCHAR(100))

    IF @Budget_Description <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @arr_str = @Budget_Description

        WHILE LEN(@arr_str) > 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(100)

            IF CHARINDEX(',', @arr_str) > 0
                SET @Description = SUBSTRING(@arr_str, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @arr_str))
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET  @Description = @arr_str
                SET @arr_str = ''
            END

            INSERT INTO  @Temp_table VALUES (@Description)

            SET @arr_str = REPLACE(@arr_str, @Description + ',', '')
        END
    END

    SELECT
        EBM.Transaction_ID,
        EBM.Transaction_Date,
        EBM.Start_Date,
        EBM.End_Date,
        EBD.Description,
        EBD.Amount,
        EBD.SL_Code
    FROM
        dbo.EXPENSE_BUDGET_MASTER EBM
    INNER JOIN
        EXPENSE_BUDGET_DETAIL EBD ON EBD.Expense_Budget_ID = EBM.Expense_Budget_ID 
    WHERE
        EBD.Description IN (ISNULL((SELECT column1 FROM @Temp_table), EBD.Description))
END
```

Now, what I am trying is to get records while passing array of values to the stored procedure parameter. If I pass a single value into the stored procedure parameter, I get a single record. But if I pass multiple values, I get below error. Please help me on this.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Using a [table valued parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/5285/table-valued-parameters#t=201612271408189061507) instead of a delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're already accept the answer above. But you can do also in this way:

1st you can declare variable:

```
DECLARE @TempCount bigint
```

Now after your while loop put below this in your code:

```
if exists (select * from @Temp_table)
        begin 
         set @TempCount = 1
        end
    else
        begin 
         set @TempCount = 0
end
```

Now update your where clause:

```
AND (
        (@TempCount = 1 AND EBD.Description IN (select column1 from @Temp_table) )
        OR (@TempCount = 0 AND EBD.Description = EBD.Description )
    )
```

Now you can get your desire result without using any multiple select queries as mentioned in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be the syntax error in this line

```
Where
            EBD.Description  in (ISNULL((select column1 from @Temp_table),EBD.Description))
```

Change this line to

```
Where


       EBD.Description  in (select ISNULL(column1,EBD.Description) from @Temp_table)
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

```
-- demo 'UPS,AC'
ALTER PROCEDURE demo
    @Budget_Description varchar(500) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @arr_str VARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @Temp_table Table (column1 VARCHAR(100))

    IF @Budget_Description <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @arr_str = @Budget_Description

        WHILE LEN(@arr_str) > 0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(100)

            IF CHARINDEX(',', @arr_str) > 0
                SET @Description = SUBSTRING(@arr_str, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @arr_str))
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET  @Description = @arr_str
                SET @arr_str = ''
            END

            INSERT INTO  @Temp_table VALUES (@Description)

            SET @arr_str = REPLACE(@arr_str, @Description + ',', '')
        END

         SELECT
        EBM.Transaction_ID,
        EBM.Transaction_Date,
        EBM.Start_Date,
        EBM.End_Date,
        EBD.Description,
        EBD.Amount,
        EBD.SL_Code
    FROM
        dbo.EXPENSE_BUDGET_MASTER EBM
    INNER JOIN
        EXPENSE_BUDGET_DETAIL EBD ON EBD.Expense_Budget_ID = EBM.Expense_Budget_ID 
    WHERE
        EBD.Description  IN (select ISNULL(column1,EBD.Description) from @Temp_table)

   END

   IF @Budget_Description IS NULL or IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Description FROM @Temp_Table WHERE Description IN (SELECT Description FROM EXPENSE_BUDGET_DETAIL ))
   BEGIN

    SELECT
        EBM.Transaction_ID,
        EBM.Transaction_Date,
        EBM.Start_Date,
        EBM.End_Date,
        EBD.Description,
        EBD.Amount,
        EBD.SL_Code
    FROM
        dbo.EXPENSE_BUDGET_MASTER EBM
    INNER JOIN
        EXPENSE_BUDGET_DETAIL EBD ON EBD.Expense_Budget_ID = EBM.Expense_Budget_ID 

   END

END
```

Comment: Your answer is work well when I provide array or signal value parameter to store procedure. But I want also that when I provide null parameter then I want show all records. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `all records` ? And what do you mean by **provide null parameter**, do you mean `@Budget_Description`? If so, you cannot parse NULL to this parameter, because this is the string parameter that your later parameters depend on to start `WHILE` loop, otherwise the `@Temp_Table` will be empty, unless you add NULL comparison in you code, I will give the answer below again, check it.

Comment: Not sure whether this is what you meant for `all result`

Comment: all records means that in my where clause if `column1` is null then show records by matching `ebd.description`. Is that clear?

Comment: `@Temp_Table` will only be NULL if you did not specify any input value for `@Budget_Description`, I am guessing that you want to see the full result if there is no matching `description` from your ebd.description, check my updated answer

Comment: Exactly If there is no matching `EBD.description` against `column1` then `EBD.description in (EBD.description)` and get all result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131618/discussion-between-ahmer-ali-ahsan-and-long).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider table value parameter for your sp. check this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx